# Java android built -in scanner KT50

Tags: java, android

I have a problem with build scanner in KT50 . I have a editText and when I start scann a result text put on edit text. But I want to block put scanned result or delete old and put new . But I don't have Idea how I can do this. How I can block put a result to edit text?

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: @just I do nothing when for example click edit text and I start scanning a text result is put into edit text and I don't know how